# Why is Word for Macintosh losing author attribution upon each save and not showing spelling errors?

Tags: spell-check, microsoft-word-2011, change-tracking

I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 and have one document that behaves differently than others when doing change tracking.  For some reason, only in this document, whenever I save, all change tracked edits and comments lose my attribution and only say `Author`.  Further, spell check is not underlining words with red even though the preference to `Hide Spelling Errors in this Document` is **not** selected.  Other documents show spelling errors normally.

Is this just a corrupted Word document and I should create a new one, or is there some feature in Word that I am not aware of that would account for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably received this file from another person and they have configured the file to have this behavior.

To change this configuration for the document, do the following:

1. Go to the `Word` menu and select the `Preferences…` menu item to bring up the `Word Preferences` dialog / control panel.
2. Under the `Personal Settings` section, find the padlock icon labeled `Security` and click it to reveal the `Security` settings dialog / control panel.
3. Under the `Privacy options` section, find the checkbox labeled `Remove personal information from this file on save` and uncheck it.
4. Once unchecked, when you save the document, you will preserve the identity of the change tracking.